# Partial instead of full markers are shown in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}        
            \addplot
            [
                red,
                solid,
                mark=x,
                domain=-3e-3:3e-3,
                samples=50
            ] 
            {exp(-x^2/(2e-3^2))/(1e-3*sqrt(2*pi))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

the markers look fine, see

[image]

, but when I replace `solid` with, for instance, `loosely dashed`, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}        
            \addplot
            [
                red,
                loosely dashed,
                mark=x,
                domain=-3e-3:3e-3,
                samples=50
            ] 
            {exp(-x^2/(2e-3^2))/(1e-3*sqrt(2*pi))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

the markers only show partially instead of fully, see

[image]

. How can I use `loosely dashed` with full markers showing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can tell PGFPlots to use unbroken lines for the markers by setting `mark options=solid`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}        
            \addplot
            [
                red,
                loosely dashed,
                mark options=solid,
                mark=x,
                domain=-3e-3:3e-3,
                samples=50
            ] 
            {exp(-x^2/(2e-3^2))/(1e-3*sqrt(2*pi))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```